# Java recursive methods - findMax and countPositive

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, bufferedreader

I'm having trouble with some recursive methods. I'm writing a program that reads in a sequence of integers from standard input until 0 is read, and stores them in an array (including 0). `findMax` keeps returning 0, and `countPositive` and `SumDivisibleBy3` seem to be off by a few numbers most of the time. I also need help with implementing `public static int exists(int[] array, int lastIndex, int searchElement)` to search the array.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int [] nums;
        nums = new int [100];
        InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);   
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
        String line = buffRead.readLine();
        try {    
            while (line.equals("0") == false && i<100) {        
                i++;        
                line = buffRead.readLine();     
                nums[i]=(int) Double.parseDouble(line);     
            }      
        } catch(IOException e) {        
            System.out.println("Array index out of bound");   
        }

        int findM = findMax(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
        int countP = countPositive(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
        int divis3 = computeSumDivisibleBy3(nums, 0, nums.length-1);

        System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + findM);
        System.out.println("The count of positive integers is " + countP);
        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers divisible by 3 is " + divis3);       
    }

    public static int findMax(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
    {           
        int max = 0;
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            return numbers[startIndex];
        } else if (numbers[startIndex] < numbers[endIndex]) {
            return findMax(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
        } else {
            return numbers[startIndex];
        }       
    }

    public static int countPositive(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
    {           
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {   
             if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
             {   
                  return 1;
             }   
             else
                  return 0;      
         } else {
           if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
           {       
            return 1 + countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex); 
           }
           else        
               return countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex);
        }
    }

    public static int computeSumDivisibleBy3(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
    {           
        if (startIndex == numbers.length - 1) {
            return numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0 ? numbers[startIndex] : 0;
        } else {
            return (numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0 ? numbers[startIndex] : 0) + computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, ++startIndex, endIndex);
        }
    }

//  public static int exists(int[] array, int lastIndex, int searchElement) {

    //}
}
```

Comment: This it not a recursive problem. Use a loop.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Looks recursive to me: `findMax`, `countPositive`, and `computeSumDivisibleBy3` all call themselfes recursively. **Edit:** sorry, misread. You're right, it should not be a recursive problem.

Comment: It *should not be* a recursive problem.

Comment: This is a recursive problem in the context of the programming class that I bet OP is taking. And no, we will not do you homework for you.

Comment: Never said the code had no recursivity, however, handling it recursively is the worst possible implementation. Have more than 500 elements, and be sure to hit a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your findMax, your logic is wrong.
You want to compare the first integer to the max value of the last n-1 elements :

```
public static int findMax(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
{
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
    } else {           
        int max = findMax(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
        if (numbers[startIndex] < max) {
            return max;
        } else {
            return numbers[startIndex];
        }
    }       
}
```

Your `countPositive` looks correct to me. Perhaps you call it with wrong input parameters.

Your last method is also wrong. You are not using `endIndex` when checking for the stopping condition.

It should be :

```
public static int computeSumDivisibleBy3(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
{
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0 ? numbers[startIndex] : 0;
    } else {
        return (numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0 ? numbers[startIndex] : 0) + computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}
```

I just moticed the `exists` method. First of all, I'd change the return type to boolean. Then I'd do a similar recursion to what you did in the other methods - a special handling of a single element array, and combining the testing of the first element with the recursive call for the last n - 1 elements of the array.

```
public static boolean exists(int[] array, int lastIndex, int searchElement) 
{
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex] == searchElement;
    } else {
        return (numbers[startIndex] == searchElement) || exists(array, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: findMax works correctly now but exists has to be done as an int rather then a boolean and startIndex and endIndex don't work in it.
Also what would be a good way to call countPositive?

Comment: @steelcode you are calling countPositive fine. What should exists return?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int computeSumDivisibleBy3(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (startIndex==endIndex) {
        if(numbers[startIndex]%3==0) {
            return numbers[startIndex];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else  {
        if(numbers[startIndex]%3==0) {
            return computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers,startIndex+1, endIndex)+numbers[startIndex];
        } else{
            return  computeSumDivisibleBy3(numbers,startIndex+1, endIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it might be worthwhile if you explained your answer, rather than posting a block of code